# What are the text used to search specific fields in Windows Search and Outlook called?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, terminology

When you search for files in the Windows explorer Search bar or in Outlook there are fields you can specifiy like `content:` for text found in the file or `type:` for the file extention of the files you want to search; and likewise in Outlook you can search for `from:` or `to:` fields in the emails.

What are these things called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What are these things called?

Search **Parameters**.

> The Advanced Query Syntax (AQS) is used by Microsoft Windows Desktop Search (WDS) to help users and programmers better define and narrow their searches. Using AQS is an easy way to narrow searches and deliver better result sets. Searches can be narrowed by the following **parameters**:
>
> - File kinds: folders, documents, presentations, pictures and so on.
> - File stores: specific databases and locations.
> - File properties: size, date, title and so on.
> - File contents: keywords like "project deliverables," "AQS," "blue suede shoes," and so on.
>
> Furthermore, search parameters can be combined using search operators.

Source [Advanced Query Syntax (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx)